# Scroll parent view's CollectionView to reveal cell before modal dismissal

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am attempting to mimic the iPhoto custom animation of shrinking an image from full screen into its thumbnail. One of the quirks is if you open an image in full screen, then swipe through enough so that the relevant thumbnail for the image you're viewing would not be visible in the parent view's collection view, then it needs to scroll it to visible *before* dismissing the modal. This is so the image has a thumbnail to animate to.

I am calling a method to do that from within my animator, but when the subsequent call happens to retrieve the imageview for the visible cell, it crashes because the Collection View hasn't scrolled yet. I've tried implementing delays, but it doesn't help.

```
// controller with the collection view    
guard let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) as? GalleryViewController else { return }

// controller with image
guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as? PhotoViewController else { return }

// this performs the scroll; implementation below
toVC.scrollToShow(index: fromVC.selectedIndex)

// this is where it crashes, as the cell doesn't exist yet
guard let toImageView = delegate?.imageView(for: fromVC.selectedIndex) else { return }
```

And the code for showing the cell:

```
func scrollToShow(index: Int) {
  let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
  if collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) == nil {
    // only scroll the cell to the top if it isn't visible
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
  }
}
```

Lastly, where it crashes, the delegate method:

```
func imageView(for selectedIndex: Int) -> UIImageView {
  let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: selectedIndex, section: 0)) as! GalleryCell
  return cell.imageView
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you state the error you are getting. Also when user taps on a cell after showing the large image view can you scroll the thumbnail view. That way when the user dismisses the large image view you are not scrolling because scrolling has already been done

Comment: yeah it's simply a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when attempting to get the cellForItem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. At the point of crash, I `po collectionView`'d and noticed the contentOffset was what it should have been, but `cellForItemAt:` wasn't called. So I tried forcing the collectionView to layout:

```
...
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
collectionView.setNeedsLayout()
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
...
```

And this worked. I suppose iOS was optimizing and only going to update it in the next layout cycle.